# No Audio Drive detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - LG Gram 14 2-in-1

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and have no audio drive detected. I am using a LG Gram 14 2-in-1. Ubuntu Kernel is 5.4.0-45.

Here's what I know:

1. `sudo lspci` outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (AGP disabled) (rev 03)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 01)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 02)
00:08.0 VGA compatible controller: Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V virtual VGA
```

2. There is no Audio Device. `sudo lspci -v` outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (AGP disabled) (rev 03)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01) (prog-if 80 [ISA Compatibility mode-only controller, supports bus mastering])
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=8]
    Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [virtual]
    Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=8]
    Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [virtual]
    I/O ports at ffa0 [virtual] [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 02)
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 9
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4

00:08.0 VGA compatible controller: Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V virtual VGA (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Kernel driver in use: hyperv_fb
    Kernel modules: hyperv_fb
```

3. PulseAudio Visual Manager only shows a dummy output:
   [PulseAudio Visual Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1k8C.png)

4. `alsamixer`gives me this:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

5. This does not work:

   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio`
   `sudo alsa force-reload`
6. $ vim */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* outputs are:

```
 autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp55
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp55
```

I'm at my wits end. There's a lot of info about no sound, but in almost all cases they detected an audio device. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question to add the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia`

Comment: If you can't load *alsamixer* that probably means *alsa-utils* is not installed. If you run `dpkg -l|grep alsa`, do you see *alsa-base* and *alsa-utils* installed? If you have just done an installation, you need to run the following commands: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: @cmak.fr `sudo lshw -C multimedia` does not reveal any outputs. Nothing shows up.

Comment: @PaulBenson running `dpkg -l|grep alsa` i see alsa-base ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5</pre> and alsa-utilis shows ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu1                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA

I believe that means they are installed? I also did `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` & all packages are up to date.

Comment: Strictly speaking if there's no entry on sudo lspci -v for Audio Device then I assume that the kernel has failed to provide a driver which should be an automatic procedure. Are you using a sound card, and have you had an earlier version of Ubuntu on same machine where sound worked? Need to see contents of */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*.

Comment: @PaulBenson thanks for sticking by. I am not using a sound card, and have never had an earlier version of Ubuntu on this machine. I used VIM to open the contents because it originally wasn't giving me the permission to. Please see the edits I made to the original post. I found another page that suggested I add *options snd-hda-intel model=laptop position_fix=1 enable=yes* to the end of that file, but it didn't work. Still no sound. I'll keep looking into this file, but please let me know if you see anything that stands out.